# Personalizar o preview da página para as redes sociais

Tags: html

Estou construindo o meu site e comecei a testar compartilhando ele nas redes sociais, mas quando aparece o preview ele "puxa" imagem e texto aparentemente aleatório. 
Como eu consigo personalizar esse preview? Obrigado

Comment: Como foi feito o sistema, usou algo pronto? Seria interessante ver o que vc tem de código.

Comment: oww devia ter sido mais especifico nesse ponto, foi mal. Fiz em HTML, CSS e um pouco de JS. Não usei nenhum framework.

Comment: Depende da rede social em questão, mas é bastante comum utilizarem as metatags. Por exemplo, para o Facebook veja [Um guia de compartilhamento para Webmasters](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters?locale=pt_BR)

Comment: Era isso mesmo que estava buscando Anderson. Obrigado pela ajuda!